# Facebook API – Graph Search - get number of event attendees

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook API Graph Search to explore queries such as:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&fields=name,description&type=event`

I need to get a list of events by a defined query (without code, SDKs, only url, it’s important for me) with number of attendees for all of events, but this information isn’t as fields, it’s the node of an event. A list of attendees of particular event can be returned with this url:

`https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/attending`

Is there any solution to get number of attending. For all events with one url? I mean the same way like fields?

Can I create more specific, complex query within url? FQL is deprecated.

EDIT:
I need this statistics of all events in one call, not for single event.

Answer (score 2):

Use this call: `/331218348435?fields=attending.limit(1).summary(true)`

With "summary(true)", you will get a "summary" in the result:

```
"summary": {
  "count": 1458
}
```

If you want to get the attendees count of several Events at once, you can use Batch Requests with up to 50 API calls in one batch: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Comment: all right, thanks, but this call retuns number for one event (with id in calling). I would get all events list in one query and get all numbers of attedings for everythinng. is it possible?

Comment: that´s not possible afaik, but you can use batch requests to make it faster. i will add a link to my answer.

Comment: well, not exactly, check out the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: "The FQL and REST APIs are no longer available in v2.1" - so if you created your app after August 7, 2014, you can´t use FQL anymore. In older Apps you can still use it until August 7, 2016.